# Optimizing the A-Star (A*) Path Finding

Tags: python, algorithm, a-star

I recently coded the A* pathfinding algorithm in Python. This is based on a coordinate system where each coordinate has a value which is its elevation and there is a maximum elevation difference (the difference between the elevation of 2 adjacent nodes) which decides whether we can move to that node or not.
How do I optimize this more?
Also, any suggestions to improve the code or if you see any feedback if I am going wrong anywhere are welcome!

I tried multiple heuristics like the distance formula but the one mentioned here seems to be working best for me. Correct me if I am wrong.

```
def astar(target_cord):

    def find_neighbor_astar(current):
        neighbor_mat = dict()
        current_matrix_cord = matrix[current[0]][current[1]]
        for x in neighbor_scope:
            for y in neighbor_scope:
                x_cord = current[0]+x
                y_cord = current[1]+y
                if(x != 0 or y != 0):
                    if((x_cord) >= 0 and x_cord < max_cols and y_cord >= 0 and y_cord < max_rows and abs(current_matrix_cord - matrix[x_cord][y_cord]) <= elevation_max):
                        if(x!=0 and y!=0):
                            neighbor_mat[x_cord, y_cord] = 14 + abs(current_matrix_cord - matrix[x_cord][y_cord])
                        else:
                            neighbor_mat[x_cord, y_cord] = 10 + abs(current_matrix_cord - matrix[x_cord][y_cord])
        return neighbor_mat

    def getheuristic(current, target_cord):
        # return (int(abs(((((target_cord[0]-current[0])**2)+((target_cord[1]-current[1])**2))**0.5))*10))
        dx = abs(current[0] - target_cord[0])
        dy = abs(current[1] - target_cord[1])
        return (dx + dy) + (2**0.5 - 2) * min(dx, dy)

    parent_cord = {start_cord: (None, 0)}
    frontier_nodes_heap = [(0, start_cord)]
    frontier_nodes = dict()
    frontier_nodes[start_cord] = 0
    node_gofx = dict()
    node_gofx[start_cord] = 0
    explored_nodes = set()
    while frontier_nodes_heap:
        curr_node = heapq.heappop(frontier_nodes_heap)[1]
        del frontier_nodes[curr_node]
        curr_cost = node_gofx[curr_node]
        if(curr_node == target_cord):
            return tracepath_ucs(parent_cord, target_cord)
        explored_nodes.add(curr_node)
        for x, step_cost in find_neighbor_astar(curr_node).items():
            gofx = curr_cost + step_cost
            path_cost = gofx + getheuristic(x, target_cord)
            if x in explored_nodes:
                continue
            if(x not in frontier_nodes):
                if(x not in parent_cord):
                    parent_cord[x] = (curr_node, step_cost)
                heapq.heappush(frontier_nodes_heap,(path_cost,x))
                frontier_nodes[x] = path_cost
                node_gofx[x] = gofx
            elif(x in frontier_nodes and path_cost < frontier_nodes[x]):
                frontier_nodes_heap[frontier_nodes_heap.index((frontier_nodes[x],x))] = (path_cost, x)
                frontier_nodes[x] = path_cost
                parent_cord[x] = (curr_node, step_cost)
                node_gofx[x] = gofx
    return []
```

Comment: maybe more suitable to ask here: 
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please check [Which site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in) for general issues.
Unless you have a demonstrable problem, you probably do not have a question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: building that fresh `dict` in every call to `find_neighbor_astar` is way too slow.  You should expand that inline at the call site and don't use an intermediate data structure.

Comment: According to my knowledge, it gives a path cost 2 more than the actual path cost. For a 1000x1000 matrix, this happens. No idea why